# PHP Check string contain #(any)

Tags: php, jquery

**Answered in here [How do I extract words starting with a hash tag (#) from a string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639478/how-do-i-extract-words-starting-with-a-hash-tag-from-a-string-into-an-array)**

I use php code to get any value containing hash "#"
for example input

```
$var = "Hello, now i am in #hotel_indonesia #today";
```

I want to select string "hotel_indonesia" and "today" automatically in php output
What syntax do I need to use?

I want output like this, because I want to save it into database

```
$var = array('hotel_indonesia','today');
```

Comment: Regular expression is your friend!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand the question. Can you show the output you expect for this value?

Comment: @Vohuman i trying to looking your answer now, thanks