# How do I get a specific string value from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have to get a value which contains "#" in the string.

```
Ex:
$string = '#1234 Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, #rm1345 print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups';

Expected results:
 #1234 and #rm1345
```

How should I get the above results from the $string?

I tried the below method, but it doesn't help me.

```
$contents = str_word_count($string, 2);
echo 'contents: <pre>';print_r($contents);echo '</pre>';
```

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your regex and generated string

```
$string = '#1234 Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, #rm1345 print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups';

$temp = preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/', $string, $matches);

echo implode(' and ', $matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
#1234 and #rm1345
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4e3371366de3a66b2c50cf1e4036594cbe52cab).

Regex testing [link](https://regex101.com/r/W8873t/1).(preg_match_all to match all # appended words).

Source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639493/6556397).

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: @RameshMoorthy Welcome. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.